# Don't understand why Mathematica is complaining about my Graph expression; how can I fix it?

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks, graphics3d, bugs, version-9

The `Tube` in `Arrow` problem is **fixed in version 10.**  Note that in version 10 `Graph3D` must be used with 3D coordinates.

---

In *Mathematica* 9.0.1, when I evaluate

```
Graph[PolyhedronData["GreatRhombicosidodecahedron", "SkeletonRules"],
  VertexCoordinates -> 
    Thread[Table[i, {i, 1, 120}] -> 
      PolyhedronData["GreatRhombicosidodecahedron", "VertexCoordinates"]]]
```

No error message was printed, so `Quiet` is ineffective, yet the output is highlighted in 'error red' and on mouseover it states:

> Coordinate index -1 is out of range for the enclosing GraphicsComplex.

However, the coordinates have clearly been implemented in the `Graph`, so I would like to simply silence this error *just as* `Quiet` *or* `Off` *would* for  error messages.

I've only encountered this problem in the above context, but suspect the solution is simple. Does anyone know of a solution?

Comment: I can reproduce your problem, but can't see anything wrong with your code. I suspect a bug in _Mathematica_'s rendering algorithm has surfaced here. Could be wrong because I have little experience with `Graph`.

Comment: Replacing `Graph` with `Graph3D` and running your command on the Raspberry Pi produces the desired error-free output.  I'm sure v10 will be out for the masses any day now.

Comment: @bobthechemist Thanks for letting me know.  Excited to not have to bypass the error anymore (not to mention the rest of *v10*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**tl;dr**  In version 9 `Tube` inside of `Arrow` is not handled correctly. This bug is fixed in version 10.

Version 10 and later explicitly supports 3D coordinates for graph vertices, but only when using [`Graph3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Graph3D.html).

---

I was surprised that `Graph` supports 3D coordinates at all (!!).  Layout algorithms supported in `Graph` are 2D only.

The problem doesn't seem to be with `Graph` itself but the `Graphics3D` object it translates to.  Here's a smaller example of the same:

```
Show@Graph[{1 -> 2}, VertexCoordinates -> {1 -> {0, 0, 0}, 2 -> {1, 0, 0}}]
```

`Show` converts it to a `Graphics3D` object.  If you look at the input form, you'll see expressions of the form `Arrow[Tube[{1, 2}]]` where `1` and `2` stand for 3D coordinates.

This is a valid and documented specification for 3D `Arrow`s and this works fine in `Graphics3D`:

```
Graphics3D@Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}]]
```

But this doesn't seem to work:

```
Graphics3D@GraphicsComplex[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}, Arrow[Tube[{1, 2}]]]
```

It causes the errors you see.

I consider this to be a bug.  I'm optimistic it'll be fixed in the next release, but of course it's always a good idea to report bugs you find to support!

Until then, you can use one of two workarounds: either replace `Tube` with `Line`, or get rid of `Arrow` (then you won't see the direction of edges).

If `g` is your `Graph`, then just do

```
Show[g] /. Tube -> Line
```

or

```
Show[g] /. Arrow -> Identity
```

Comment: Thank you, Szabolcs.  The latter (Arrow -> Identity) allows for what visualization I need without resorting to `GraphPlot3D` (retain styling defaults of `Graph`, too).  Glad to possibly have found a bug and to have prompted an answer from you.  Will wait little bit for good measure, then accept an answer.

Answer (score 6):

Wrong use of `Graph` in this case I believe. I think the following does what you're after:

```
Graphics3D[{FaceForm[], EdgeForm[Blue], 
  PolyhedronData["GreatRhombicosidodecahedron", "Faces"], 
  PointSize[Large], Red, 
  Point /@ PolyhedronData["GreatRhombicosidodecahedron", 
    "VertexCoordinates"]}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: Just as a clarification to my answer: I completely agree that to plot this in 3D, your solution should be used.  It looks like 3D vertex coordinates are not documented so probably not supported in v9 ... when I said I believe this is a bug I was referring to the fact that `Arrow[Tube[...]]` doesn't work inside `GraphicsComplex`.  That's a graphics bug, not a graph one.

Comment: @Szabolcs: No need to clarify, but appreciated. Yes, the whole ability to even get a 3D result for a graph is I think a side-effect of `Graph` using the underlying graphics primitives, and the vertex info gets passed along. Neat that it works, but who knows what will or won't work for undocumented features / effects in the future.

Comment: We'll have [Graph3D](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graph3D.html) in the future for this :-)